# A hotkey to rotate objects as I'm placing them from the asset library?

Tags: objects, asset, library

I've been using several assets from my asset library on scenes.

Some of them properly snap to a surface (such as the object with the green checkmark, it's meant to be a poster on a wall), but others will snap via their edges, like the other object under it.

It's also meant to be a poster, so I wanted it to snap to surfaces using its face.

So I think this topic has 2 questions, actually:

1 - Could someone point me at a tutorial on how to edit how my asset files' snap to things? I haven't grasped yet how the object "understands" which edge or face will snap onto the other object in the scene. Seems like it's about editing the asset library object's origin?

2 - As a quick fix, is there a hotkey or another way for me to rotate objects from the asset library as they're being placed in the scene (whey they're outlined with yellow lines and haven't been set on the scene yet, such as the spike in the example below) This would save me some time placing things while I don't edit my library.

Thank you!!

[image]

[image]

[image]